# tkColorChooser.askcolor window does not close when the user press Cancel

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to make a simple drawing program in python using pygame.
I want the user to choose a color, using tkColorChooser.askcolor.
The dialog pops up when the user presses b. It works fine when the user chooses a color. But if the user presses Cancel in the askcolor window, the program goes on running, but the askcolor window does not close.
It stays open on top of the other window, with the Cancel button pressed.

What am I doing wrong?

I am posting a simplified code where the problem appears.
I am running it under Linux Ubuntu 11.10, Python 2.7.2+, python-pygame 1.9.1release-0ubuntu4

Thank you!!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pygame
from Tkinter import *
import tkColorChooser 

def main():
   # Colors
   black = (0,0,0)
   yellow = (252, 229, 3)
   bgcolor = black
   picturecolor = yellow

   running = 1

   # Initiate the screen 
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.RESIZABLE)
   screen.fill(bgcolor)
   pygame.draw.circle(screen, picturecolor, (200,200), 10, 0)
   pygame.display.flip()   

   # Initiates the Tk
   root = Tk()
   root.withdraw()       

   while running:
      event = pygame.event.poll()
      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_b:
            ctuple,cstr = tkColorChooser.askcolor(initialcolor=bgcolor, title = 'Choose picture color')
            if ctuple != None:
               picturecolor = ctuple
               screen.fill(bgcolor)
               pygame.draw.circle(screen, picturecolor, (200,200), 10, 0)
               pygame.display.flip()
         if event.key == pygame.K_x:
            running = 0
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         running = 0

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: tkColorChooser (py3k colochooser) is working perfect in win7 with py3.2. Cancel is working as expected using the posted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you seem to be doing wrong is that you're not starting the event loop by calling `root.mainloop()`. Whether that's the actual problem or not, I don't know. However, Tkinter isn't designed to work without the event loop running so it's not surprising that you're getting odd behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see that combining pygame and tkinter is not that easy. I guess pygame is not what I need, I will give a try to TK canvas.

Comment: @Santiago: your code works for me in python 3.2 (names adapted) and in python 2.6.6 (unmodified) in  windows XP and win7 64 bits, respectively... did not try in ubuntu though